# problem when creating audio context in LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl, openal

When I try to create audio context in LWJGL 3.3.1 I get this error:

[ALSOFT] (EE) Failed to set real-time priority for thread: Operation not permitted (1)

here is the code:

```
String defaultDeviceName = ALC10.alcGetString(0, ALC10.ALC_DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPECIFIER);
audioDevice = ALC10.alcOpenDevice(defaultDeviceName);
    
audioContext = ALC10.alcCreateContext(audioContext, (IntBuffer)null);
ALC10.alcMakeContextCurrent(audioContext);
    
ALCCapabilities alcCapabilities = ALC.createCapabilities(audioDevice);
ALCapabilities alCapabilities = AL.createCapabilities(alcCapabilities);
```

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: It just means that your audio may lag a little bit, tho from my experience it still works fine all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I found a typo and it is now working.